# Convert String to ASCII Values

Tags: javascript, ascii

I'm trying to add the ASCII value of each element in S1 and S2 (strings), and return true if they're equal to each other. I can only seem to get the ASCII value of the first element in each string with the code below:

```javascript
function compare(s1, s2) {
  var splitS1 = s1.toUpperCase().split("");
  var splitS2 = s2.toUpperCase().split(""); 
  for (var i = 0; i < splitS1.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < splitS2.length; j++) {
      var sum1 = 0;
      var sum2 = 0;
      sum1 += splitS1[i].charCodeAt(0);
      sum2 += splitS2[j].charCodeAt(0);
      return sum1 === s2;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement is ending the function during the first loops. Instead, you should only return if it fails.

```
function compare(s1, s2) {
  var splitS1 = s1.toUpperCase().split("");
  var splitS2 = s2.toUpperCase().split(""); 
  for (var i = 0; i < splitS1.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < splitS2.length; j++) {
      if (splitS1[1].charCodeAt(0) === splitS2[j].charCodeAt(0)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was at this line of code:

```
return sum1 === s2;
```

You should be comparing it to `sum2`

```
return sum1 === sum2;
```

Working example: https://repl.it/FrI2

EDIT:

Since `s2` is the string itself while `sum2` is the ASCII sum.